# Shell script to create a folder with files name and copy files inside

Tags: bash, scripts, sh

I have a list that looks like this

```
ABC_100.0_k_1x1x1.xyz
ABC_100.0_k_1x1x1.txt
ABC_100.0_k_2x2x2.xyz
ABC_100.0_k_2x2x2.txt
ABC_100.0_k_10x10x10.xyz
ABC_100.0_k_10x10x10.txt
ABC_600.0_k_1x1x1.xyz
ABC_600.0_k_1x1x1.txt
ABC_1000.0_k_1x1x1.xyz
ABC_1000.0_k_1x1x1.txt
```

I want to write a script that creates the following folders

```
ABC_100.0_k_1x1x1
ABC_100.0_k_2x2x2
ABC_100.0_k_10x10x10
ABC_600.0_k_1x1x1
ABC_1000.0_k_1x1x1
```

I've tried the following

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *_???.*_?x?x?.*
    do
        dir=${file%}
        dir=${dir%.*}
        mkdir -p "./$dir" &&
        scp -r "$file" "./$dir"
done
```

But I'm only getting the folders

```
ABC_100.0_k_1x1x1
ABC_600.0_k_1x1x1
```

What am I doing wrong? Maybe this is stupid but this was my first attempt at shell scripting

Comment: ? only matches one char you should try to loosen up your match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *_*.*_*x*x*.*
    do
        dir=${file%}
        dir=${dir%.*}
        #if [ ! -d "$dir" ];
        #then
                mkdir -p "./$dir"

        #fi
        scp -r "$file" "./$dir"
done
```

The symbol ? replace a single character, so it fits only the sequence 1x1x1 or 2x2x2, not 10x10x10 (10 is made by two characters).
I've added an if statement just to avoid recreating the same folder.

Comment: the if statement isnt needed mkdir with `-p` will skip if dir exists.

Comment: commented if statement after bac0n suggestion. I didn't notice the flag :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and dirty script that works:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.???
    do
        dir=${file%.*}  # cuts off the suffix
    mkdir -p $dir
    scp "$file" "$dir"
    done
```

Some of your files do not match the pattern *_???.*_?x?x?.*

Answer (score 0):

If all files are paired, with either a `.txt` and `.xyz` extention, then a simple solution would be

```
for file in ABC*.txt
do
   mkdir `basename $file .txt`
done
```